# How to apply CSS animation only on a single image when there are multiple images?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations, keyframe

I need to apply "fadeInOut" animation to my CSS code. I have two images in the background, positioned on top of each other. I have used CSS keyframes to define two states - one with top image opaque, one with it transparent. How do I get this only on the first (top) image and not on both?

```
#hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(../img/1.jpg), url(../img/2.jpg);
  background-position: top center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;


  animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
  0% {opacity:1;}
  45% {opacity:1;}
  55% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:0;}
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
 #hero {
   background-attachment: fixed;
  }
}
```

Below is the html code.

```
<section id="hero">
   <div class="hero-logo">
     <img class="" src="img/logo.png" alt="img_logo">
   </div>
   <div class="actions">
     <a href="#about" class="btn-get-started">Get Strated</a>
     <a href="#services" class="btn-services">Our Services</a>
   </div>
</section>
```

I want only the first image to get transparent, so that the second image is visible and so on. Please help.

Comment: Add the relevant html code too!

Comment: you can take the top image in the `<img>` tag and then apply fadeInOut animation on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like

**HTML**

```
<section>
  <div id="bgimg">
    <div  id="hero">
     <div class="hero-logo">
       <img class="" src="img/logo.png" alt="img_logo">
     </div>
     <div class="actions">
       <a href="#about" class="btn-get-started">Get Strated</a>
       <a href="#services" class="btn-services">Our Services</a>
     </div>
     </div> 
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
#bgimg{
    background: url(../img/2.jpg);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(../img/1.jpg);
  background-position: top center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;


  animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
  0% {opacity:1;}
  45% {opacity:1;}
  55% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:0;}
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
 #hero {
   background-attachment: fixed;
  }
}
```